# Standardisation of errors within my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

So I've been trying to standardise all the error handling within my application but I've not been able to standardise all.

First I replaced the IExceptionHandler by a custom exception handler by replacing it in the WebApiConfig like so

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
```

After this almost all exceptions were handled using a specific error standard I want to use.

Shortly after, I noticed that my OWIN exceptions weren't caught in this so I created a middleware which is inserted before any other OWIN pipelines so it can catch the OWIN exceptions and once more return in standardised format.

Now I'm stuck with a new problem. When using ASP.NET WebAPI I try to create a few REST API's. Most exceptions caused by the validations within these API's are caught and standardised by the CustomExceptionHandler but not all.

When performing a GET request with an identification, for example:

```
.../test/api/superhero/marvel/wolverine%20
```

I get a default 404 from IIS. The reason is obvious. I'm looking for a resource which doesnt exist because of the encoded space in my URL. I've made sure to catch these kind of exceptions as well if I were to perform a request which I did not register such as:

```
.../test/api/superhero/ma4rvel/wolverine
```

But for some reason I can't catch this exception caused by a rogue encoded space. I've been looking into this and the closest I've gotten to influencing this is by using the IIS web configuration customError. While this is an option to do, I simply do not want to use MVC Views for this and want this solely to rely on C# compiled code.

So here I am wondering if anyone can offer me another option.
I should clarify that this is far from a must have and is more of a nice to have. An exception caused by something like this isn't going to happen very often and I'm fine with that, but if I'm able to fix this and once more standardise my errors then I'd be happy.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps the problem is that the 'ma4rvel' part of url is required for creating controller instance and without controller instance your middleware is not called?

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski thanks for answering but I don't think that's the case at all. Not only is the middleware only used for OWIN (i.e. authentication) I'm simply stating that exceptions caused by miswriting the URL (such as the 'ma4rvel') are actually handled by the CustomExceptionHandler. I created the API by using RoutePrefix and Route. Meaning the controller has a Prefix like so '[RoutePrefix("test/api/superhero")]' and the resource in question has a Route like so '[Route("ma4rvel/{heroname}")]'.

So if I understood you correctly, that's definetly not the case.

Comment: You get 404 because the error message come from IIS pipeline. Have you tried to bypass IIS error and let your asp.net pipeline to handle all exceptions?

Comment: @JokiesDing Thanks for commenting. I did try. All I can manage to find is to use customErrors in the web.config but this requires the usage of MVC views as far as I can tell. Unless you have another way to do that?

Comment: So nobody has any clue?